# How to Add or edit Column with Closure fail on Yajra datatables query collection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, datatables, query-builder, eloquent, yajra-datatable

the  https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/edit-column example says

```
$model = App\User::query();
return DataTables::eloquent($model)
    ->addColumn('intro', function(User $user) {
        return 'Hi ' . $user->name . '!';
    })
    ->toJson();
```

I don't know who is user? Is it like User as $User? User is each row?

So I try

```
$search_alls=
    DB::table('a16')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('name','=','john')
        ->get();

return DataTables::collection($search_alls)
    ->addColumn('newclass', function(User $user) {
        return 'Hi ' . $user->id . '!';
    })
    ->toJson();
```

I got the common error

> DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

How can I use the closure on add or edit column?
I want use if condition to add one column value a class to show the icon.

the below is the edit example I still don't know how to use as I does not know which is use or $user? Can anyone explain for me? thanks~

```
use DataTables;

Route::get('user-data', function() {
    $model = App\User::query();

    return DataTables::eloquent($model)
        ->editColumn('name', function(User $user) {
            return 'Hi ' . $user->name . '!';
        })
        ->toJson();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = App\User::select('*')
                ->where('name','=','john');

return DataTables::collection($data)
                 ->addColumn('newclass', function($data) {
                      return 'Hi ' . $data->name . '!';
                 })
                 ->toJson();
```

Also rememeber, if you are trying to display HTML content, then you need to add the name of the created column ('newclass' in this case) to the "raw" param of the datatables config file. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what escapeColumns([]) does?

It looks to me like it disabled ALL HTML escaping by setting NO columns to apply HTML escaping. This may be an easy way to fix one problem, then leads you into a dangerous situation in other circumstances.

append **escapeColumns([])** after addColumn

```
->addColumn(){...}
->escapeColumns([])
```